# XmlDocument vs XmlWriter

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I see you can create xml files using XmlDocument or XmlWriter.

Are there any benefits of using one method over another?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`XmlWriter` does stream-based writing of XML data.  `XmlDocument` builds XML data as an object model in memory.

You use `XmlWriter` when you need to produce XML documents without using memory proportional to the size of the document.  You use `XmlDocument` when you need to process XML in memory - when you're parsing an existing XML document into an object model, or you're creating elements in arbitrary locations, or updating an existing document, or using XPath to search through a document.  (Actually, for the latter case you'd use `XPathDocument`, but in any event you *couldn't* use an `XmlWriter`, since it's write-only.)

Of course it's possible to write XML data to a stream using an `XmlDocument`.  But you're actually using an `XmlWriter` to do that, because that's what `XmlDocument` is using internally.

Comment: As in 99% cases `XmlWriter` would be used with a `MemoryStream` kind of backing, the memory size difference would be negligible. What is important however, is that `XmlDocument` can be validated against the schema.

Answer (score 5):

It will depend on your scenario. [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) loads the whole document into memory, while [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) uses a stream so it is better suited when working with large XML documents. On the other hand XmlDocument might be easier to use.

Answer (score 4):

If you support .Net Framework 3.5 I would advise you to work with XDocument and XElement instead. It is a much simpler and friendlier API

Answer (score 1):

XmlDocument stores hole data in the memory, so it is slow when file is big(500 mb and more) but easy to use XmlWriter writes to stream directly